# API Whatsapp - How to Implement Profile Picture

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

1° I created a Whatsapp Icon for an online shop.

2° I use whatsapp business.

3° I`m trying to implement a profile picture to be seen (as follows the link below). When someone clicks on the whatsapp icon (link), the link will open a new window and we can see a profile picture like this.

I have search a lot on google but I did not find any solution that shows how can I do this.

I have searched also here, but I did not find the answer: https://faq.whatsapp.com/

I appreciate any help or if someone knows a tutorial that I can read, that would be very helpfull.

[Profile Picture Sample](https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=5521979903996&text&app_absent=0)

[image]